# Geoserver SLD: Dynamic BBOX Thematic Shading

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I'm not sure if this is possible within Geoserver so wanted to ping to the community. I have a table in a database (~3m rows), this table has a column of counts in it and I want to thematically shade the data by Equal Count or Equal Range or % buckets (such as 0-25%, 25-50%, 50%-75%, 75%-100%) using ONLY the data being returned in the Bounding Box.

I do not want to hardcode the count ranges (Low: 0-100, Med: 100-200, High: 200-300) into the SLD because if I move the map to an area where the counts are quite low I'll end up with all similar colours (for example if the area only has counts < 100 then it'll all be one colour) where in reality I want to see color range within the set of data being returned. E.g: If the colour range from the bounding box is 1-50 I want to be able to show Low/Med/High using Equal Count/Ranges applied to that 1-50 range.

I wasn't sure if this was possible within Geoserver and before I try to embark on this I wanted to check.

Hope that makes sense?

Many thanks,
Ben

Tried reading the documentation and searching but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [SLD Rest Service](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/sldservice/index.html) to do this.

> The SLD Service is a GeoServer REST service that can be used to create
> SLD styles on published GeoServer layers doing a classification on the
> layer data, following user provided directives.
>
> The purpose of the service is to allow clients to dynamically publish
> data and create simple styles on it.

Comment: Ah thank you Ian!

So I've installed the gs-sldservice-2.19.3.jar and xom-1.1.jar to the C:\Program Files\GeoServer\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib location and restarted the service.

I then checked .../geoserver/rest/ webpage but I only see the service sldservice/capabilities...have I missed a step in the installation process ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I have ever actually used it - does it respond to the rest requests?